# Did I design these tables correctly?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4, relational-database

Here's the scenario...A person can have a user record, with or without an associated profile record.  That person can also have multiple profiles that he/she "manages" (family member, etc), those profiles may or may not have user records associated with them since they may or may not use the website/app.

A profile record contains personal information such as name, dob, etc... So we can have grandma Smith's profile with her personal info but no associated user record since she will never use the site herself, only her daughter will.

The important fields are listed below (is this a properly normalized set of tables?):

USERS: id, email, password, profile_id (FK, NULLABLE)

USER_PROFILES: id, user_id, profile_id

PROFILES: id, name, dob, user_id (FK, NULLABLE)

I guess what I'm wondering is, if I'm supposed to have BOTH a profile_id foreign key AND a user_id foreign key, are these redundant?  In my site I have a profile edit page where you can edit a person's user info and profile info on the same page so I'd like to be able to provide either a profile ID OR a user id from a referencing page and pull up the appropriate data.  This is hard to do if I have no user_id in the profiles record to see if the current profile has a user record or not.

Comment: final answer was rewrite table as such:

User: (id, ...)
Profiles: (id, user_id, ...)
Owners: (profile_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your table structure correctly, it looks like profile_id is redundant.  id in USERS is your link to PROFILES, where it resides as a foreign key in user_id.

As for how you are querying it... I'm a bit concerned.  Shouldn't you require a user id and then allow the user to view and edit all associated profiles? That seems in keeping with current practice and should resolve your dilemma that made it necessary to have profile_id in USERS.

Still, even if you keep your current setup, the user id can be used to query the profiles, and the profile id can be used to query profiles, so you are set either way.

Comment: the "id" field in each table is merely the PK auto increment field.  Profiles.user_id is the FK to Users.id.  

I also failed to mention the User_Profiles table, which is where the profiles under a given user are held.  So a single user can have a profile that describes THAT person, OR entries in the User_Profiles table of profiles that they manage.

So to answer your question, the user_id field in the profiles table is actually pointing to the user that is directly connected to that profile.

Comment: So Profiles is the profile for the user, while User_Profiles are the profiles that the User manages, right?  So the User's own profile will not be in User_Profiles?  I ask because if the User's own profile is in User_Profiles, you can get rid of UserProfiles.user_id since User_Profiles.profile_id will be sufficient to get the profile and the user (assuming Profiles.id is the primary key for Profiles).  Put another way, ALL your profiles can go into just one profiles table, and you can  mark special profiles by putting IDs in another table (ala Set membership).

Comment: No, a user's own profile is referenced in users.profile_id, it will not be in user_profiles.

Comment: Why not add it and simplify your tables?  You can basically follow ids around to get what you want.  It may complicate your queries somewhat, but it will reduce redundancy.

Comment: So, you're saying remove profile_id from users and user_id from profiles and simply add a record into user_profiles for the user himself?

Comment: Sort of.  Instead of two profile tables, have one table that holds all profiles (user owned and managed), then another table that has the profile ids that represent the user.  Some people would just use a field in the profile table as a flag, but I don't think that's considered best practice in tables.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19551/discussion-between-jarrette-and-user1161318)